# node-fetch: why is `signal` recommended over `timeout`?

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

The `node-fetch` documentation suggests that using `signal` is recommended over `timeout`, but doesn't offer any hints as to why:

```
{
    // These properties are part of the Fetch Standard
    ...
    signal: null,       // pass an instance of AbortSignal to optionally abort requests
 
    // The following properties are node-fetch extensions
    ...
    timeout: 0,         // req/res timeout in ms, it resets on redirect. 0 to disable (OS limit applies). Signal is recommended instead.
    ...
}
```

(source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Why is that? In what situations would it be a problem to use `timeout`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure (hence why I'm commenting instead of submitting an answer), but my guess would be that it's not a problem to use timeout, it's just more flexible to use the signal. An AbortSignal can do everything a timeout can, but it can also be aborted on many other triggers besides a timeout (like an incoming event from some other system). I think that's why it's preferred: the broader usability. Again, I could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The `timeout` option is a `node-fetch`-proprietary extension that is not part of the [WhatWG fetch standard](https://github.com/whatwg/fetch).

When it was built, `AbortController` did not exist in the standard yet, so the library offered `timeout` as a workaround.

Adding a non-standard feature to a library that is supposed to implement the standard as exactly as possible has problems:

- Extra features tend to 'creep out' of the library when people use it: If they use the feature, the code is potentially not future-proof: If they have to replace the library for some reason, their code might not be compatible to other implementations of the standard that will not have the added feature. This is a form of [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).
- Other code might expect an implementation to match the standard exactly and fail to compile, for example when using TypeScript. In this case, the library could not be used.
- Now that `AbortController` exists, the library has to maintain two ways of aborting requests, which means more maintenance work and [more potential bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/41953).

By discouraging the use of this non-standard feature, less code will break when the authors will eventually [deprecate and remove](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/523) the feature.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments of your code timeout is just a node-fetch extension. AbortSignal is the new (future?) standard way to cancel and the only cross platform way that cancelling `fetch`

Comment: What do you mean a node-fetch extension? it's most likely just passing `timeout` to the underlying `http.request` options: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback

Comment: @caub it's an extension to the whatwg standard - ie not part of the official 'fetch' specification, which node-fetch seeks to implement. https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/